# Change scala Enumeration id

Tags: scala, enums

I want to create `enum` type with `value` that can be changed.
Consider the following:

```
object Type extends Enumeration
{
  var a = Value(0, "some string1")
  val b = Value(1, "some string2")
  val c = Value(2, "some string3")
}
```

I gave every `enum` field a `value` but i want to have the option to change this `value`.
And another is that i am reading this `values` from some table so `enum` with same value its a option.
Is it possible ?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good use case for `Enumeration`. You want a mutable `Set`, perhaps.

Comment: `var` in an `object` = global mutable state = not a good idea.

Comment: Just curious, why you want to model your enumeration that way at all? Just for sake of proof if it is possible, or do you have a real use-case for that? It is definitely not a use-case for enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

In common parlance, an enum is not something that is mutable. The elements are enumerated at compile time, as typesafe constants.

Also, `Enumeration` is relatively fragile.

```
scala> object X extends Enumeration { var x = Value(0, "a") ; def f() = x = Value(1, "b") }
defined object X

scala> X.x
res1: X.Value = a

scala> X.f()

scala> X.x
res3: X.Value = b

scala> X.values
res4: X.ValueSet = X.ValueSet(a, b)
```